# how to fix mobile layout issue

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

**This is my app link**
[collegefellow.social/users/login](https://collegefellow.azurewebsites.net/users/login)

**My code repo** [github](https://github.com/smileynanda99/collegefellow) ( login page=> /views/login.ejs )

**Layout issue**
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BePPg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `max-width: 100%` to `.container`:

```
.container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #0811202d;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 400px;

    max-width: 100%; /*add this it*/
}
```

And remove `width: 400px` from `.row`:

```
.row {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    height: 90px;

    /*width: 400px;*/ /*remove this it*/

    background-color: #D03737;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's work, but not for a big-screen according to my requirements. it gives me an idea of how can I fix it, thanks again, man.

Comment: If my answer helped you, then mark it as solved by checking the checkbox to the left of my answer. Thanks.